# Compiling the Unit Test Framework of Boost

Tags: boost, compilation

I am trying to follow the instructions to compile the **unit test framework** of **Boost** (see, the *Standalone Compilation* section at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/compilation/standalone.html ).

But I get the message **'bjam' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file** as entering **bjam [-sTOOLS=] {-sBUILD=boost_unit_test_framework}** into the Windows shell meanwhile this exactly is what the documentation reads.

Isn't there a trick such as now one has to use the command **b2** instead of **bjam**?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be running "./bjam", to indicate where bjam is (i.e., in the current directory)?

The error messages seems to be suggesting that, but I have little experience with Windows shell.